# Multi tasking in gtk application

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, multitasking

I have a GTK application where I need to run few task parallel. Application receives data from a serial port and then depending upon the data, it has to display text on label and play audio. I am using an event based serial communication which makes a flag high if the data is received.

In the main loop, I have created 3 threads which I am running infintely.

```
Thread1 to read serial data
Thread2 to display data on gtk label
Thread3 to play audio
```

Thread1 gets activated when it receives signal from the serial port event. After reading the data, it sets a flag high which then activates Thread2. Thread2 then decodes the serial data and display its information on label. It then sets another flag high which activates the Thread3 and then Thread3 plays an audio file.

I need to run Thread2 and Thread3 in parallel. So that the text displayed on label and audio should be done at the same time. Currently I am doing something like below:

```
Thread2
{
  while(1)
  {
    if(serialData == TRUE)
    {
       //decode the serial data and display it
       startAudio = TRUE  //Indicate Thread3 to play audio
       serialData = FALSE
    }
   }
 }

 Thread3
 {
   while(1)
   {
     if(startAudio == TRUE)
     {
       //play audio
       startAudio = FALSE
     }
   }
 }
```

At current situation, I do not have much serial data to decode, so text displayed and audio both looks synchronized. But what if the data is large then I guess they both will not be sync. Is there any way I can run these task in parallel.?

Comment: If you use asynchronous libraries (like Gio, Gstreamer) there should be no reason to use threads for the tasks you mentioned. I'm not saying you can't use them, but avoiding threads if you can is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set `startAudio = TRUE;` in thread 1 instead of thread 2, for example just after you set `serialData = TRUE;`.

Another solution is to set `startAudio = TRUE;` in thread 2, but before decoding the data, not after.

If you want the display of data, and not the decoding, to be synchronized with the sound, then what you did seems to be the best solution, because I think once the data is decoded, it doesn't take a lot of time to display it. However, you can try to set `startAudio = TRUE;` before the display of the data, but after decoding, so displaying the data and playing the sound will be done in parallel.

But if displaying the data can take a lot of time, then the only way I see to make the display and the sound seem to be synchronized, is to play the sound just after the displaying have finished, so you will need to set `startAudio = TRUE;` just after the GTK call that updates the label.

Another way to synchronize threads is to use conditions, it is more complex than your implementation, but when a thread is waiting for a condition, it uses much less CPU than for variable checking in your implementation.